# Using curl with VS2017, x64

Tags: curl, 32bit-64bit

No duplicate: I have read several articles about compiling Curl but I have still trouble and it seems to be a 32 vs. 64 bit problem. This is what I did:

- Open the "x64 Native Tools command line prompt for VS2017"
- Unzip curl7.64, cd to winbuild and
- C:\repoWOF\dev\3rdParty\curl-7.64.0\winbuild>nmake /f Makefile.vc mode=dll VC=15 ENABLE_WINSSL=yes MACHINE=x64

This command creates builds/libcurl-vc15-x64-release-dll-ipv6-sspi-winssl/ with the bin, lib and include subdirs as expected and I can even run

```
C:\repoWOF\dev\3rdParty\curl-7.64.0\builds\libcurl-vc15-x64-release-dll-ipv6-sspi-winssl\bin>curl.exe
curl: try 'curl --help' or 'curl --manual' for more information
```

...which is an indication that libCurl works. However, when libCurl is linked with another software then this software crashes ("This application was unable to start correctly (0x00007b)"). I have used Dependency Walker with libcurl.dll and with the final software (netlicensing) that crashes. Here is the output for libcurl.dll:

[image]

And here is Dependency Walker for the netlicensing software:

[image]

..it shows two entries with x86 instead of x64 which is *presumably* the problem. I can only imagine that these two libs (SSLEAY32.DLL and LIBEAY32.DLL) come from Curl. Any hints?

Answer (score 1):

Found a workaround: SSLEAY32.DLL and LIBEAY32.DLL where the problem. I downloaded x64 versions (for whatever reason they are also named xxx32.dll) and placed them into the dir of the executable.